# Why does emplace_back use parameter pack as argument?

Tags: c++

I am writing my own version of Standard library in C++. When it comes to the `emplace_back` function in vector, I see signature like the following.

```
template 
<class... Args>
void emplace_back (Args&&... args);
```

I thought it can accept multiple elements and emplace them at once at first because that's one benefit for using parameter pack, but the description shows that the function only emplace one item at a time. I look at other implementations of this function and they also just handled one item.

Why does C++ use parameter pack in this case?

Comment: "emplace" means "construct in place". So it needs the  arguments for the constructor.

Comment: @ted: how does what i said contradict that? You can pass multiple arguments to a single constructor. You cannot invoke multiple constructors, whether copy constructors or otherwise.

Comment: @rici Okay, I was unclear in the first comment. I wanted to disambiguate whether the OP was wondering why they shouldn't be able to pass in both multiple arguments to construct an element *and* multiple elements. It seems like their confusion lies in why you can pass multiple arguments but just construct one element, so wanted to know if they were thinking something else for their implementation.

Answer (score 1):

> Why emplace_back use parameter pack as argument?

Because classes can have constructors that in general may accept any number of arguments. In order to forward any number of arguments, we need to use a variadic argument pack.

> I thought it can accept multiple elements

It does not. It accepts zero or more arguments for the constructor of single element.

Comment: Hi eerorika, could you provide an exmaple?

Comment: @Harry An example of what?

Comment: @Harry, If you have a vector `v` of `std::string`, `v.emplace_back(5, 'a')` will add "aaaaa" to the vector just like `std::string s(5, 'a'); v.push_back(s);` except done in one step instead of copying or moving the string in.

Comment: @eerorika How does the parameter pack forward arguments to the constructor?

Comment: @Harry Like this: `std​::​forward<​Args​>(​args)...`

Comment: @chris I think I got it. Thank you.

Comment: @eerorika Why can't we just use void emplace_back (T&& element);

Comment: @Harry Because then you have to create the element before passing it in, which then requires you to copy the newly created element into the container. That's just unnecessary work when all you want to do is create an element in the container.

Comment: @Harry Besides what Ted explained, we already have `push_back(T&&)`. We don't need another function doing the same thing.

Comment: @eerorika Except for classed which does not support a move assignment.

Comment: @gerum How would "`emplace_back (T&& element)`" - suggested by Harry - be different from the existing `push_back(T&&)` in case of classes which do not support move assignment?

Comment: I think somebody (maybe me) is confused. push_back(T&&) is ok for classes which have a move assignment. An additional emplace_back(T&&) would not have any additional use case, but it is useful to have an emplace_back (Args&&... args) for all classes which does not support move semantic.

Comment: @gerum Exactly. Hence, an answer to the question *"Why can't we just use `void emplace_back (T&& element);` [instead of `emplace_back (Args&&... args)` that we have]"* is *"because we already have `push_back(T&&)` and we don't need another function doing the same thing"*.